# Uploading a file to Sitecore keeping the extension in the DisplayName

Tags: c#, file-upload, sitecore, pipeline, sitecore7

As the title says, I'm trying to upload a file to somewhere in my Sitecore tree from the web and I want to keep the file's extension in the DisplayName of the item.

I tried using MediaCreator, but it requires a specific filepath which I do not know when I let people select a file using asp:FileUpload. So that's no good.

I'm now using the asp:FileUpload in combination with a pipeline. When I use Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save from Sitecore.Kernel it works except it removes the extension of the file from the DisplayName. So I created a custom pipeline method that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using Sitecore.IO;

namespace Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload
{
    public class CustomSave
    {
        public void Process(UploadArgs args)
        {
            foreach (string key in args.Files)
            {
                var file = args.Files[key];

                if (file != null && file.FileName.Length > 0 && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var filename = FileUtil.MakePath(args.Folder, Path.GetFileName(file.FileName), '/');
                    try
                    {
                        if (!args.Overwrite)
                        {
                            filename = FileUtil.GetUniqueFilename(filename);
                        }
                        file.SaveAs(filename);

                        EventDispatcher.DispatchTrace("File has been uploaded: " + filename);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error("Could not save posted file: " + filename, ex, this);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I now face is that it's trying to save to my C:\ disk instead of the Sitecore database.

Any suggestions on how to write to the correct destination?

The end goal, as explained, is to use the client friendly asp:FileUpload to select a file and upload it to a specific path in Sitecore retaining the file's extension in its DisplayName. If you have another way to do that I'd like to hear about it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting that appends file extension to the item name 
"Media.IncludeExtensionsInItemNames". If you can live with that, just turn it on.

Otherwise, I'd add a custom processor into "uiUpload" after "Save" one. At that moment you would already have a list of created media items from "args.UploadedItems". You can do your simple manipulations with items in there.

Comment: I can't use Media since it requires filepath which I don't have. The other idea I was getting into. I got confused, tried to change Item.DisplayName but it has no setter. Turns out Item.Name works. Thanks.

Comment: If you use Item.Name to add extension, then just use the setting. It'll do that automatically for you.